# QT3 linker errors after switching to another compiler

Tags: qt, gcc, linker, qt3

I have created simple test project that uses QT3 gui. The main function is as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication a(atgc, argv);
    MainWindow *w = new MainWindow;
    w->show();
    a.setMainWidget(w);
    a.exec();
    if(w) delete w;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it like this:

```
qmake
make
```

it is ok (the used compiler is g++-2.95.4). But when I do this:

```
qmake
make CXX=g++-3.3.6 LINK=g++-3.3.6
```

I get tons of link errors like this:

```
.obj/main.o(.text+0x27): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `QApplication::QApplication[in-charge](int&, char**)'
.obj/main.o(.text+0x66): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `QApplication::setMainWidget(QWidget*)'
.obj/main.o(.text+0x6e): In function `main':
: undefined reference to `QApplication::exec()'
```

It seems like it has not linked qt libraries properly. Is there any idea how to build project using any other compiler? I am using linux RedHat.

Comment: Have you cleared all before `make`s?

Comment: Yes, i did `make clean`